# How to create and empty SpatialLinesDataFrame in R

Tags: r, spatial-analyst, sp, sf

I need to create and SpatialLinesDataFrame with a predefined structure (9 fields). I'm performing a function over a list of shp which I want to append to this empty spatiallinesdataframe.

I already know how to save each shp within a folder and then merge all, but now, I'd like to merge all the sph within the iteration to avoid save and reread steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this trick, which is to create a 1-row SLDF with the right attributes, and then drop the first and only row, leaving you with nothing:

```
> library(sp)
> library(raster)
```

Here's the beef:

```
> s = SpatialLinesDataFrame(
  sl=SpatialLines(
   LinesList=list(
     Lines(
       list(
         Line(
           coords=matrix(c(0,1,0,1),2,2)
         )
       ),ID=1)
      )
    ),
  data=data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3))[-1,]
```

Set up a one-line data frame with your attributes in the last line - here I've got three. The finale `[-1,]` drops the one row created, leaving you with:

```
> s
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 0 
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 3
names       :    a,    b,    c
```

A SLDF  with no rows (features) and 3 variables.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot ¡